# Rendering javascript section from partial view via AngularJS in MVC 4

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have seen many tools over the internet to load scripts/css (whichever is applicable) from a Partial View in MVC 4. I have tried the below tools and everything seems to be working fine when I load the partials normally. But the issue is whenever I load the partial views via AngularJS the partial views scripts/css files are not getting rendered. Does anyone face this same issue?

1. Forloop.HtmlHelpers
2. Cassette
3. Other extensions

Comment: show the code you are using. I also sense you don't have a strong understanding on how AJAX works fully (I am not criticising, just an observation).

Comment: Actually I am calling the Views from AngularJS (Single Page Application model) so I assume it considers this as a partial view.

Comment: What version of AngularJS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities here.

1) You are not loading jQuery before AngularJS.  jQuery is required to get this behavior (see links in #2).

2) Your issue could be related to [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3756) issue with AngularJS which was introduced with AngularJS 1.2.0.rc1 and fixed in AngularJS 1.2.2 with [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/c47abd0dd7490576f4b84ee51ebaca385c1036da) commit.